# My singleplayer submarine crewmember died, can I revive them?

Tags: barotrauma

I was playing Barotrauma with friends first, and there the crewmembers would revive after a mission. Now my main character died and he did not revive even after the mission was finished.

Is that it? Can I revive them or are they dead forever?